# Substitute fields in a record in a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

In a matrix table, i have Part as Row and Vendor as Column and price as data, if for a part say 'bearing' there are two vendors say A and B selling for $ 10 and $ 8 respectively, i want the group aggregate column to display the name of the vendor who is the cheapest rather than the min price value across every row, how do i substitute the min price value with the name of the vendor.

```
         Vendor
```

Part-------------- A -------------        B -------------------    Cheapest
Bearing  --------10----------------     8  ----------------------    B

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a `Lookup` expression, with the minimum price as the value to match. This expression should give each vendor if there is a tie for the cheapest:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Min(Fields!PRICE.Value), Fields!PRICE.Value, Fields!VENDOR.Value, "pv"), " / ")
```

There may be a more elegant solution out there, but is the first one I found.